# Can $\exp(W(\sqrt{\ln(\sqrt{n})})$ be an integer?

Tags: nt.number-theory, special-functions

Let $W(z)$ be the Lambert $W$ function and $n$ a positive integer. Is it possible that $\exp(W(\sqrt{\ln(\sqrt{n})})$ is an integer?

If $\exp(W(z))$ is an integer, say $k$, then we get $\frac{z}{k}=W(z)$ and hence $k=\exp(z/k)$. So for all positive integer $k$ there is exactly one $z$ such that $\exp(W(z))=k$, namely $z=k \ln(k)$. If now $z=\sqrt{\ln(\sqrt{n})}$, we get that $\ln(n)=2k^2\ln^2(k)$.

Can this equation have an integer solution for given $n$? (For $n=1$ this is clear).

Comment: Strikes me as unlikely that there would be integers $n>1$ and $k$ such that $(\log n)/(\log k)^2$ is rational.

Comment: This is what I thought, too. But unlikely does not mean impossible ;)

Comment: a motivation for this question might help... why this particular combination of square roots and logs?